# Several Django signal receivers in one module

Tags: python, django

I have separate python module for signal receivers, it's called `signals.py` and imported in `ready()` method of my `AppConfig`.

In this module I implemented `post_save` and `post_delete` signal receivers for specific model and registered them via decorator:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def generate_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ...
```

And it works fine.
But, when I added to `signals.py` receivers of same signals in the same manner, but from different specific models:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=AnotherModel)
def generate_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ...
```

My functions stopped to receive signals. But if I move receivers into separate python modules `mymodel_signals.py` and `anothermodel_signals.py` and import both modules in `ready()` then all of them works again.

Why it isn't possible to keep receivers in one module?

Answer (score 1):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
@receiver(post_save, sender=AnotherModel)
def generate_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if sender.__name__ = 'MyModel':
       # Bar
    else:
      # Foo
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want both functions to have the same behaviour? If yes, you can do:

```
def do_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ...

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def generate_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    do_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender=AnotherModel)
def generate_another_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    do_smth(sender, instance, created, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Nope, my functions do different things. 
My question isn't about how to implement described behavior, it's about why such behavior isn't work :)